# ++group((int)(value[i])/10); what does it do..? in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, increment

This program is for calculating students marks frequency

```
float value[50];
int group[11] = {0};

for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

    scanf("%f",&value[i]); /* reading of values */

    ++group[(int)(value[i])/10)]; /* what does this line do.? */
}
```

Comment: What does it do? It invokes UB.

Comment: @not-rightfold: what's undefined about it?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: oh, true. i either missed that or assumed that was just to show the type

Comment: @claudiu ,@ShafikYaghmour , i have edited the code , check it!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line:

```
++group[(int)(value[i]) / 10)];
```

Is the same as:

```
int flooredValue = (int)value[i];   //e.g. 3.5 becomes 3; 12.6 becomes 12
int groupIndex = flooredValue / 10; //division discarding the remainder
group[groupIndex] += 1;
```

What does it mean, though? Well here's how it ends up converting the values:

```
value[i]  |  groupIndex
----------+------------
3.5       |  0
12.6      |  1
18.6      |  1
23.1      |  2
57        |  5
94.6      |  9
100       |  10
```

So it ends up counting how many marks fall into each bucket of 10. Scores from 0 to 9.9999 fall in the "0" bucket, from 10 to 19.99999 in the "1" bucket, etc. Note the following, though:

```
value[i]   |  groupIndex
-----------+------------
-3.5       |  -3
155.6      |  15
```

As it is now, your input could certainly be less than zero or over 100. If that happens, you're going to write into memory outside of the bounds of `group`. This will lead to very unpleasant behavior. Check either that the input value is in bounds or that the group index is in bounds before indexing into the `group` array.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: ah of course, thanks. modified to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ++group[(int)(value[i])/10)];
```

lets divide this

```
1. (int)(value[i])/10)
```

for example value[i] is 51 it will result 5 as you are using  casting to int.

```
2. ++group[5]; // is same as group[5] += 1;
```

pre incrementing value of `group[5]`

Answer (score -1):

In sub-expression

```
(int)(value[i])/10)
```

`value[i]` is of type `float`, dividing it by `10` will give `double` value (after default promotion). But array subscripts should be of integer type, `(int)` is used to cast the return value of sub-expression to integer .
In expression

```
++group[(int)(value[i]) / 10)];
```

prefix `++` is used to pre-increment the array element `group[(int)(value[i])/10)]`.

Comment: it is pre increment.change it in your answer.btw i did not down voted this.